# speed control not showing for youtube video in mediaelementjs

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm using mediaelement.js to play different types of videos. Its working properly for .MP4 videos. However speed control not showing for YouTube videos.

I have tried below code for same.

```
$('video, audio').mediaelementplayer({
        pluginPath: 'dist/',
           features: ['playpause',  'current', 'progress', 'duration', 'speed', 'skipback', 'jumpforward', 'tracks',
           'markers', 'volume', 'chromecast', 'ads', 'vast', 'contextmenu','fullscreen'],
                       startVolume: 1, 
                       speeds : ['0.5','1.00','1.50' , '2.00'],
                       success: function(mediaElement, node) {
                      
                  },
               error: function() {
                       //alert('Error setting media!');
                  }
       });
```